# Concat data and store in database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on a project where I have 3 input fields with different names values. For example:

```
<input type="text" name="name1"> 
<input type="text" name="name2"> 
<input type="text" name="name3">`
```

and I have stored the POST values in `$name1, $name2 and $name3` (for example).

But I have only 1 field in database say `user_name`. What I want to do is to store all the 3 names in the same field as a comma separated value. I am new to PHP here and I have heard that it can be done by concatenation and implode function or something. However I am unaware of the process.

Comment: please try to learn basics first, you could have easily solved it if you have given efforts

Comment: also please do not tag-spam adding everything you can think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$new_value_to_be_stored = $name1 .",". $name2 .",". $name3;
```

use concatenation like so.Hope it helps !

Answer (score 3):

Both will work concatenation and `implode()`. I'll show you both:

Concatenation:

```
$value = $_POST['name1'].",".$_POST['name2'].",".$_POST['name3'];
```

We use `implode` function on an array so to use this we have to make the form elements in array format we can do that with adding `[]` to the name:

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" /> 
<input type="text" name="name[]" /> 
<input type="text" name="name[]" />
```

Now in the php:

```
$value = implode("," $_POST['name']);
```

Since you're using CakePHP:

```
<input type="text" id="Modelname0name" name="data[Modelname][0][name]">
<input type="text" id="Modelname1name" name="data[Modelname][1][name]">
<input type="text" id="Modelname1name" name="data[Modelname][2][name]">
```

Then in the controller method:

```
$value = implode("," $this->request->data['Modelname']['name']);
```

Comment: @AD7six CakePHP is still PHP. So I believe that in your controller method `$_POST` is accessible isn't it ? It might not be the conventional way but that doesn't make the answer incorrect.

Comment: @AD7six That's why it's called `developing`. You can adjust CakePHP to work like this or a bunch of other ways.

Comment: @AD7six I suppose you're right with the inexperienced devs stuff. Added a CakePHP solution aswell.

Comment: @AD7six Funny, OP just removed the CakePHP tag.

Comment: Daan, @Peter in which case I apologise, a rather significant and annoying error for the OP to make.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest taking a different approach

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" /> 
<input type="text" name="name[]" /> 
<input type="text" name="name[]" />
```

And in PHP do the following:

```
// Convert array to string
$names = serialize($_POST['name']);
```

When you retrieve the date from the database you can do:

```
// In which $record->names is the result from your database
$names = unserialize($record->names);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$name1 = "x";
$name2 = "y";
$name3 = "z";

$user_name = $name1 .", ". $name2 .", ". $name3;

$userNameArr = explode(',',$user_name);

echo $userNameArr[0];
echo $userNameArr[1];
echo $userNameArr[2];

?>
```

Add and explode like this.....:)

Comment: Thanks bhai... ye kaam to karta hai jaisa chahiye tha.. now need to seperately display them with explode.. no idea for that :(